# Group posts by weekly or monthly

Tags: jquery, plugin-json-api

Is there an easy way to group all WordPress blog posts by Weekly or Monthly grouping. Ideally I do not want the posts to be displayed by grouping in Front Page but would like to add it as an element or attribute  so I can call it using the JSON API plugin.

My intention is to use the following JQ code to group the posts based on week post was posted:

```
$('#postlist').listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
    var out = li.attr("Enter the attribute that defines week for each posts");
return out;
}
```

Or is there a plugin that appends some weekly attributes for each posts

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but what's the use scope of `JSON API` plugin here?

The only thing you need is ad the week (or wahtever information you need) in the markup of the page.

Assuming your loop is somethin like this:

```
<ul id="postlist">

  <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <li id="post_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
  </li>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

You should only add the week information:

```
<ul id="postlist">

  <?php
  while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  $week = get_the_time('W');
  ?>

  <li id="post_<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-week="<?php echo $week; ?>" class="post">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
  </li>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

After that your js code can be (please proper enqueue it on the page):

```
$( "#postlist" ).listview({
  autodividers: true,
  autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
    var out = 'Week ' + $( li ).data('week');
    return out;
  }
});
```

I'm not an expert of jQuery UI Mobile, but this should work.

Comment: where would the php code be inserted?

Comment: In the template file that display the post list. If you are using a 3rd party theme you should create a child theme. @Chelseawillrecover

Comment: OK just wanted to validate that's what you meant. The postlist is a container in my JQuery Mobile code. I have seen similar codes else where but was hoping to do this via JQuery. OK let me add this into my website template file and see how it goes. Thanks